# Install GTK Inspector in 22.04

Tags: themes, 22.04

I am trying to add [Mica](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/mica) to the Yaru theme. I guess the easiest path is using GTK Inspector. It would be nice to know how to install it in 22.04. Any help will be great.

Comment: Not sure if it would help with that but, ... You don't install **GtkInspector** ... [You just enable it](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK/Inspector).